# How to understand "taking in the abrupt return to normality"

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

> Harry stood quite still, all his senses vibrating, **taking in the abrupt return to normality**. After a moment, he became aware that his T-shirt was sticking to him; he was drenched in sweat.

I don't quite understand the use of "*taking in*" in this phrasing "*taking in the abrupt return to normality*". Should we understand it as *[taking] [in the abrupt return to normality]* or *[taking in] [the abrupt return to normality]*? What sense of 'take' is being used here?

Comment: [Take in](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/take_in) - at Wiktionary

Comment: @CowperKettle, I'm not sure which sense should apply in this context. I might need some explanation on that. Thanks!

Comment: "taking in the abrupt return to normality" is a rather quirky use of the phrase **to take in**, IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would gloss the phrase as "to experience something via one or more of the senses; to begin to comprehend what one has perceived via one or more of the senses".

> Her eyes took in the room.
>
> It took him a few minutes to take in all that she had said.
>
> The cameras flashing, the reporters yelling questions at her, the confetti falling down around her—she was feeling rather overwhelmed as she took it all in.

Answer (score 1):

In the context you cited **taking in** is used as a phrasal verb, definition #5: To attend or experience, from [The Free Dictionary](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/take).

Consequently, your quote reads:

> Harry stood quite still, all his senses vibrating, **attending (experiencing)** the abrupt return to normality. After a moment, he became aware that his T-shirt was sticking to him; he was drenched in sweat.